# cross compiler issues with dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c++, memory-management, cross-compiling, ansi-c

I wrote a program for an assignment in which I allocated memory in this way:
`EdgeBucket* edgeTable[ n_scanlines ];`. I understand that this is normally illegal in C, but I was not aware that it could also not be done in C++. However, when I compile it using g++, it gives no compile errors. But my grader is using a visual studio, and when he attempted to build my program, it gave errors stating that the length of the array must be constant. I normally compile my programs with the -ansi and -Wall options to ensure cross compiler integrity, but even that didn't detect this. I am concerned about my grades being compromised by this, so does anyone know why the -ansi compiler didn't catch this, and what can be done to prevent further cross compiler discrepancies?

Comment: Your example is not dynamic memory allocation BTW.

Comment: If your grader is using Visual C++, you might want to download a VC++ Express version that corresponds to what they are using and build your assignments with that before turning them in. Note that  if you prefer you can still develop using g++ and whatever IDE you're using now, but this gives you an opportunity to periodically build with the same toolchain that your grader will be using. Of course, all this assumes that you have access to a Windows machine or VM to install VC++ Express on.

Comment: @JesseGood I am aware of that. That is the very reason it won't compile on my grader's compiler, hence making it the topic at hand.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Isn't -ansi supposed to make that unnecessary though? Realistically, I couldn't compile my code on every compiler to make sure it compiles.

Comment: `-ansi` is equivalent to `-std=c90` (for C) or `-std=c++98` (for C++). The docs for this option say, "The `-ansi` option does not cause non-ISO programs to be rejected gratuitously. For that, `-Wpedantic` is required in addition to `-ansi`". I suggest just using the compiler your grader is using at some point before turning in your assignment. If you don't have the resources for using more than one compiler toolchain, then I'd switch to the compiler your grader is using. It might not be your preference, but it'll make it easier to avoid problems with the grader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-pedantic-errors` flag. [Example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/5yx2Z%240).

They are known as VLAs (Variable Length Arrays). The are legal in C from C99 and illegal in C++.